# Java Pattern.compile ignoring escaped double quotes (\")

Tags: java, regex, escaping, quotes

I am having a hard time figuring out the pattern to ignore escaped quotes. 
I want this:

```
    "10\" 2 Topping Pizza, Pasta, or Sandwich for $5 each. Valid until 2pm. Carryout only.","blah blah"
```

to match as:

```
   1> "10\" 2 Topping Pizza, Pasta, or Sandwich for $5 each. Valid until 2pm. Carryout only."
   2> "blah blah"
```

I have been trying this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filteredCoupons);
```

and I get this

```
   1> "10\"
   2> ","
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9pS6/1)

In Java,

```
String pattern = "\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"";
```

Comment: I can accept this answer in 7 minutes. Which I will do. Because it worked splendidly.

Comment: Note that Pshemo's answer is actually the same, but wrapped in an alternation group. My "unwrapped" version is faster and safer since there is less backtracking steps involved.

Comment: I'm not sure how reliable the stepscounter in such as regex101 is in this case. Don't have pcretest installed right now but seems of great performance and haven't seen this approach yet.

Comment: I tested similar regex patterns at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester). Though it is tailored for .NET flavor, I think that the underlying basic mechanism is similar: the less backtracking, the safer the pattern is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your regex need to accept non-quotes, or quotes which have `\` before it. In that case try with

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(\\\\.|[^\"])*\"");
```

This part of regex `\\\\.|[^\"]` will try to find

- `\.` - any escaped character,
- (`|` or) `[^\"]` - any non-quote character

I placed `\.` before `[^\"]` to prevent `\` being matched by `[^\"]`.

In other words for text like `foo\"bar"` and regex `\\\\.|[^\"]` you will get this matching

```
foo\"bar"
^^^-matched by [^\"]

foo\"bar"
   ^^-matched by \.

foo\"bar"
     ^^^-matched by [^\"]

foo\"bar"
        ^-can't be matched by anything since there is no \ before
          nor it is non-quote
```

DEMO:

```
String filteredCoupons = "\"10\\\" 2 Topping Pizza, Pasta, or Sandwich for $5 each. Valid until 2pm. Carryout only.\",\"blah blah\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(\\\\.|[^\"])*\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filteredCoupons);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
"10\" 2 Topping Pizza, Pasta, or Sandwich for $5 each. Valid until 2pm. Carryout only."
"blah blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also could use a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?s)".*?"(?<!\\.)
```

as a Java String:

```
"(?s)\".*?\"(?<!\\\\.)"
```

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lD7cD8/1); [test at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/d5edg6) (click on "Java")

- After meeting a `"` it looks behind, if there's no preceding backslash skipping one character
- Similar `".*?(?<!\\)"` but of better performance to look behind after meeting a `"`
- Used `(?s)` flag for making the dot also match newlines

---

For interest I did a benchmark of the different versions with the sample string at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) (thanks @stribizhev for this link!). Was unsure if the stepscounter of [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is accurate here.

[image]

Used only non-capturing groups for the benchmark. Interesting was, that `"(?:\\.|[^"])*"` has almost double performance against the same with capture group `"(\\.|[^"])*"`.